# How do I query the AppEngine DB comparing two properties of the same entity?

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

I'd like to make a query to return all the entities of a given type where one property is greater than another.  For example, return all Widgets where selling price is greater than buying price.  I can't seem to figure out how to do it in the Google AppEngine datastore.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't do this directly, because the indexing model does not support complex expressions like that. You'll have to add a new property that you manually maintain as the difference between buying and selling price, then search for items where this delta property is greater than or less than zero.